# Java Duplicate Class Error - No repeated classes

Tags: java, linux

I am currently submitting a project that requires a submission in a zipped file format.  The project itself works completely fine and has no issues with compiling or running properly.  The submission checker automatically checks for compile errors, and I am receiving the following error.

```
  Compiler Output
 ./Game.java:3: error: duplicate class: mineSweeper.Game
public class Game {
   ^
1 error
```

My zip folder only contains one class called "Game".  Is there any reason why this could be occurring?
The zip file contains only Java files and png files that are used in the game itself.

This is the zip file.  Any assistance would greatly be appreciated, since I do not understand how a duplicate class error can occur when each class clearly has a unique name.

Comment: I recommend using an IDE so you won't have these problems.

Comment: I created the project in Eclipse, however, we were required to put all necessary files into a zip file for submission.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the submission requirements?

Comment: "You must submit a single archive called files.zip. The most important requirement is that it must include a Game class (it has to actually be named Game) with a main method:

public static void main(String[] args) 
This Game class must be in the default package so that we know where to look for it.

when you are ready to submit, create a temporary directory and copy everything in your src/ subdirectory into that directory. Also copy over any extra files and libraries (e.g., .jar files) that your game needs. Once you have done that, create your zip file from inside that directory. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try submitting the following file. I have made it into a jar for you.
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxMpZvaCgomHZ1lMTVI3LWZ1Nk0

Thanks

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately that still causes a compiler error.  I believe the instructions ask for the files within a single zip file, as in files.zip when opened will contain all the files at the top level.   The error I get is : GameTest.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        Class gameClass = Game.class;
              ^
  symbol:   class Game
  location: class GameTest
1 error

Comment: Seems like the original issue was fixed, but I'm left with "Menu.java:12: error: package mineSweeper.Frame does not exist
import mineSweeper.Frame.Screen;
                        ^
1 error" as an error now... not sure why this is occurring.

Comment: Ok, got the issue, can u upload this one? Fixed the packaging error
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxMpZvaCgomHUHJISU82bms5S1E

Comment: Wow, thank you so so much, this works! I really appreciate the time you took to help me with this- I was trying to fix this for hours!  If you don't mind me asking what was causing the issue?

Comment: Ok you have defined all the classes in a mineSweeper package, which was not the default package. So first of all removed that from each of the classes. Then fixed the referencing issues due to the package removal. Then your sprites/images were being  called from gfx/<imagename>. Remove the 'gfx' part from the references, so it directly references the images in your current directory. Thanks for awarding the points :-) Happy to help!!

Answer (score 0):

Export it into a runnable jar file and zip that. There's an option to include the .java files in the jar with Eclipse, IIRC.